# how to pass current authenticated user to django rest framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class Professional(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dummy_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

a serializer like this:

```
class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Professional
      fields = '__all__'
```

and a view like this one:

```
class CreateProfessional(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfessionalSerializer
```

The thing is, I need to pass the current authenticated user for a given request as the user for my serializer, I'm getting an error because obviously the user field is required as stated in my model, but I can't find an elegant way to do so, how could I go about it?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context). You can pass `request` and access `request.user` or pass `user` directly, and then access from `self.context`

Comment: @Luis Alfonso Buelvas Betancour Replacing `User` with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a recommended approach mentioned in [django´s documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Answer (score 3):

Set the `user` as a ***`read_only_fields`*** in the serializer meta. This will prevent accepting the `user` data from the payload.

```
class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Professional
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ["user"]
```

Then, override the **`perform_create(...)`** method of the view class

```
class CreateProfessional(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfessionalSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make validate method with like validate_user and do following code inside.

```
self.context['view'].request.user()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class CreateProfessional(generics.CreateAPIView):
         serializer_class = ProfessionalSerializer

        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()


    class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
           model = Professional
           fields = '__all__'

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = self.context['request'].user
```

like this you can get your current user

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice way to do it, I dont wan't to return custom responses, I will let that to the framework, what I did was the following in my view:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # redefine method to parameterize the serializer
    # while leaving the response handling to the 
    # framework
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    kwargs['context']['user'] = self.request.user
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in my serializer:

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        entity = Entity.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return entity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead of single API Views. ModelViewSet handles all the crud operations automatically.

Let's say you have the model

```
class Professional(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dummy_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

and the serializer

```
class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Professional
      fields = '__all__'
```

So you can add a ModelViewSet

```
class ProfessionalViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Professional.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ProfessionalSerializer
```

this will handle all the crud operations for your model. Following example class will show you the methods that a viewset has.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
    actions that will be handled by a router class.

    If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
    the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
    """

    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

these will handle all the actions. checkout the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) for more

you'll also have to add the router to handle all the urls automatically which is also covered in the documentation (above link). Following is an example(urls.py).

```
from myapp.views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: using a model viewset also add the request to the context automatically